# How can I select the same index for a ListBox and a ComboBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

When I select the 1st index in the ListBox, I want a ComboBox to automatically select the 1st index, too.

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean WinForms?

Comment: yes, on windows form app

Comment: On change selection of list box select event you can easily set index of combo box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [SelectedIndexChanged Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged?view=netframework-4.8) of the `ListBox`, you can set the [SelectedIndex Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem?view=netframework-4.8) of the `ComboBox` using the use the selected index of the listbox:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
}
```

This will always change the combobox item whenever the listbox selection changes. However, you did say specifically the ***first*** index, in which case you can just add a test for when the slected index is `0` if you only want the combo box to change when the first item in the list box is selected:

```
if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == 0) comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```